# How to download a file with a temporary or indirect link in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, downloading-website-files

I have been trying to download files from a site that changes the download links after some time. I tried using wget module to download those files. It does work on the direct links to file like(http://example/file.zip) but it doesn't download files from links that are temporary they change and do not seem to be direct links of the files. Those are like (http://example.com/file/) I have to use webbrowser module to open those links so it would download those files (as the webbrowser and download manager do download those files) I want to download those files directly with python 3.

(I have tried downloading with urllib and requests module)

Comment: Many sites so this specifically to prevent you from doing what you’re doing. If they have an API, you should use that instead. If not, you’re committing yourself to a possible arms race where every time you write a workaround for what they’re doing they can easily detect it and break your code (or just ban your IP), not to mention that you’re probably violating their terms of service.